# GitHub каждый раз спрашивает пароль при команде push

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-push, ssh-key

После того, как по почте пришла рекомендация сменить ключ шифрования, у меня git при каждом push начал спрашивать логин и пароль по два раза. Хочу, чтобы стало как раньше, т.е. сразу исполнялся push.

Я нашел инструкцию, как переоформить ключ. Делал всё по пунктам, как здесь написано:

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Создал новый ключ, добавил в агент, зарегистрировал в гитхабе, и это не помогло.

Comment: Ошибку даёт какую-нить или просто всё так же спрашивает логин и пароль?

Answer (score 1):

Проверь какой *remote* указан в локальном гите.

В папке где находится .git запусти:
`git remote -v`

Если там указан remote который начинается на https - [замени](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh) его на тот который начинается на *git@*

> git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git

Вот так:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

(его можно найти в твоём проекте на github.com - зелёная кнопка code, а там ssh)

Comment: теперь он сначала просит ввести yes, затем парафразу

Comment: Если я правильно понял что именно происходит, то yes нужно будет вводить только один раз.
Парафраза - это пароль? Скорее всего это пароль от локального ключа ssh - его тоже не должен просить каждый раз. Лучше всего поможет понять причину скриншот..

Comment: он так ведет себя только в том репозитории, на который я его натаскивал. На все остальные репозитории по прежнему спрашивает логин и пароль по два раза. Видимо, я вообще все сделал не так.

Comment: Будет ли спрашивать пароль зависит от настройки remote. Если она настроена на ssh - пароль спрашивать не должна. Если же на https - будет просить ввести пароль.

Comment: На счёт нескольких запросов ввести пароль - нужно удостовериться в том, что логин и пароль вводится правильно в первый раз. Если есть в этом уверенность, пришли скрин экрана (с затёрным логино и паролем, хотя его и так не должно быть видно в cli).